# Baum-Welch training example

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, hidden-markov-model, unsupervised-learning

I'm the author of a new Baum Welch trainer using MapReduce for the Apache Mahout project (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-627)

I'm looking for an example with a reasonably small data set which I can use to demonstrate the usage of the trainer I have developed.

Does anyone here know of any online demonstrations for this training which go beyond the normal "toy" examples? I'm interested in typical HMM training application areas--bioinformatics, NLP, Signal Processing etc.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example from bioinformatics that is often used to teach students how to train a HMM with Baum-Welch are the CpG islands:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CpG_island

The problem is pretty straightforward when you have sequences of CpG islands and some reference sequences, and should be solvable in short time.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't my field, so take this with a grain of salt.

I do know, however, that Hidden Markov Models play a *huge* role in speech recognition applications.  [Here's](http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/Signals%20AI/Papers/HMMs/0.pdf) a very highly-cited paper, which I believe is the basis for a lot of current methods.  I also know that the most common benchmark data set for this is called [TIMIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIMIT), although I think there are better ones now.

Hope this is useful.